# React alert not displaying with proper styles

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have installed below library for the alert dialog `npm install react-confirm-alert --save`
But unfortunately, CustomUI alert is not displaying with proper css styles. Do we add anything else ?

Imported below ones on top of the `App.js` file.

```
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'; // Import
import "react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css"; // Import css


        const removeRecord = (indexToRemove) => {
        const newList = currentRecord.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
        setCurrentRecord(newList);
      }

    function handleClickBasic(indexToRemove) {
        confirmAlert({
          customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
            return (
              <div className='custom-ui'>
                <h1>Are you sure?</h1>
                <p>You want to delete this file?</p>
                <button onClick={onClose}>No</button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    removeRecord(indexToRemove)
                    onClose();
                  }}
                >
                  Yes, Delete it!
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          }
        });
      }
```

[image]

Expected output as per live demo from the npm library link
[image]

Comment: can you add the css class code as well?  It is not clear what the expected output is.

Comment: I don't have any specific css for the the alert, as I am using an inbuilt alert and css via `import "react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css";`  I believe this should apply the css for the alert.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I don't have any specific css for the the alert, as I am using an inbuilt alert and css via `import "react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css";` I believe this should apply the css for the alert

Comment: Can you share what the expected output *should* be? or what the actual output is if the attached image is the expected? If you haven't mucked with the styling then have you inspected the DOM to see what CSS *is* being applied and if any rules are being overridden?

Comment: I did install the react-confirm alert from here ..https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-confirm-alert

Comment: If you click on the Live demo link https://ga-mo.github.io/react-confirm-alert/demo/

Comment: If we choose show confirm custom UI, you could see a nice alert there...

Comment: I am not getting that one, so I would like to know where i have messed up ?

Comment: I was thinking it will apply the css styles from the import link provided, sorry if I was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to provide the CSS for custom alert components yourself. The included `"react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css"` is for the default "basic" dialog styling.

See this example demo:

```
.custom-ui {
  background: deepskyblue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.custom-ui button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit react-alert-not-displaying-with-proper-styles]